# r calculating percentiles for identical rows

Tags: r, quantile

I am trying to calculate the percentiles of my dataframe rows.

My data looks similar to that:

```
YM      V
201401  1
201401  2
201402  3
201402  5
```

I now want to create a new data.frame, which looks like that:

```
YM     v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
201401
201402
```

In this data frame there should be e.g. in the columns v1 the first percentile of my variable for the month January 2014.

I tried to use the apply function but it did not work:

```
apply(df1, 1:2 ,quantile , probs=seq(0,1, 0.1),na.rm=TRUE)
```

EDIT:

The aggregate function `aggregate(V ~ YM, df, FUN = quantile , probs=seq(0,1, 0.1),na.rm=TRUE)` of Sotos gives out my desired output, however if i want to apply it to a new data.frame, it gives out the original output:

```
df2 <- aggregate(V ~ YM, df, FUN = quantile , probs=seq(0,1, 0.1),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Why is that?

Comment: you want `aggregate`, i.e. `aggregate(V ~ YM, df, FUN = quantile , probs=seq(0,1, 0.1),na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you, @sotos! Sorry I obviously searched wrong.